# How Can I Convert my DataFrame to other column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the `dataframe` of following type - notice the column header groups:
[image]

But I Want to convert my headers as below:

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: 1. Please do not post images of dataframes in your question. Rather put the code to reproduce them in our syatem. 2: What have you tried? you may want to look at df.swaplevel and sort_index

Comment: no swaplevel isn't giving the desired output

Comment: ok , in that case , please refer to point 1. Create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you further

Comment: this is actually stock information read from yahoo finanace as:
ticker = 'BAC C GS JPM MS WFC'
bank_stocks = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)

Answer (score 0):

i hope these codes work for you :)

```
unstack = your_df.unstack().reset_index()
unstack.columns = ["Stock Info", "Bank Ticker", "Date", "Prices"]
categories = unstack["Stock Info"].unique()
group = unstack.groupby("Bank Ticker")

con = pd.DataFrame()
for g,d in group:
    d["Stock Info"] = pd.Categorical(d["Stock Info"], categories=categories, ordered=True)
    d = d.pivot(index=["Date","Stock Info"], columns="Bank Ticker", values="Prices").unstack()
    con = pd.concat([con, d], axis=1, sort=False)

print(con)
```